# Handlebars body section

Tags: handlebars.js

I was reading a `template.hbs` and saw `{{> body }}`, but I didn't find any partials named `body.hbs`. Is it some convention that all the content in `page.hbs` will go under the `{{> body }}`?

Answer (score 2):

`{{ body }}` would be a reserved word for Handlebars as a placeholder for **ALL** content passed into the template.

**However**, since the `>` character exists, `{{> body }}` is **considered a partial** and one should expect a partial to be registered under the name "body".

`Handlebars.registerPartial('body','<div>Hello, World!</div>');`

Comment: Where can I read about ```body``` being a reserved word? Doesn't say so in the docs.

Comment: yeah. no mention of such reserved word in the docs.